# Can't connect to websocket API

Tags: python, websocket, cryptocurrency

Now I’m working on developing WebSocket to get data (ex.btcusdt) from the website FTX
since the ftx.com you can trade the crypto without having to pay fees and I have a minimum budget

so now I want to try out to get some data and making my own bot

but now I’m having a problem with how I connect to the website

since I watch Binance video I was trying the same way but still didn’t get any message from the " wss://ftx.com/ws/ "

I do not quite understand the document they provide

my question is how can I connect to the data stream for example if I want to get the JSON file of BTCUSDT or BULLUSDT

this is the document they provide
https://docs.ftx.com/#websocket-api

Thank you

My code

```
import websocket
SOCKET = "wss://ftx.com/ws/"
def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')
def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')
def on_message(ws, message):
    print("got message")
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

This works find with Binance

Answer (score 2):

Using the example code [here](https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/blob/master/websocket/client.py) modified  to accept api keys as arguments, here is an example of grabbing ticker data:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # rest = client.FtxClient(api_key=key, api_secret=secret)
    ws = ws_client.FtxWebsocketClient(api_key=key, api_secret=secret)
    ws.connect()
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print(ws.get_ticker(market='BTC-PERP'))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Chev_603 say you can copy the two files  into your directory.
Then, import the files at the begging of your app and use:

```
from client import FtxWebsocketClient
from websocket_manager import WebsocketManager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        print(ws.get_ticker(market='BTC-PERP'))
        time.sleep(0.2)

# your own api_key and api_secret must be written into the client.py lines 20 and 21
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON message:

```
import websocket
import json

this = json.dumps({'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'trades', 'market': 'BTC- 
PERP'})

def on_open(wsapp):
    wsapp.send(this)

def on_message(wsapp, message):
    print(message)

wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://ftx.com/ws/", on_message=on_message, 
on_open=on_open)
wsapp.run_forever()
```